# How to calculate exposure time for Fuji Velvia RVP 50 using a DSLR spot meter?

Tags: film, metering, zone-system

I have a couple of RVP 50 rolls I would like to experiment with -
The idea is to set up a tripod and use a Canon 5D MK2 in ISO 50 mode
for composition focusing and exposure metering, then replace the 
5D with an EOS300 and capture the photo with it.

The question is how does one translate the exposure time between the DSLR
and the film - it is known or at least believed that ISO in DSLRs does not map 
particularly well to film ASA rating, then there is the whole 12%-15%-18% 
gray metering for zone 5 confusion so if anyone has experience with this particular film and this particular camera (the 5D MK2 used for metering) I`d love to hear what ended up
working for you

Comment: Why don't you use the EOS 300 exposure meter?

Answer (score 5):

[DxO Mark](http://www.dxomark.com/index.php/Cameras/Camera-Sensor-Database/Canon/EOS-5D-Mark-II) measured the 5d mk2 ISO 50 as ISO 73, which is almost 1/2 stop off the actual. So, assuming the camera otherwise meters correctly, you can adjust your film camera to the settings on the 5d and the compensate for the half stop slower "film" speed on the sensor by faster shutter speed or using a smaller aperture.

In terms of gray metering, I don't think digital has particularly changed versus film, so I don't think I would especially worry about it.

Comment: Thanks John, I did check the DxO Mark site for the 5d mk2 ISO bias and am planning to use it but "assuming the camera otherwise meters correctly" is actually assuming that zone-5
for 5d mk2 dslr sensor is metered the same as for the rvp 50 film which is what I hope someone will tell me from experience

Comment: @silkysmooth - I think you'll find that the metering in the 5d mk2 is based on the same precepts as other spot meters, I wouldn't consider it to be an issue. Anyways, your film may have good latitude on the exposure, so being out by a half stop wouldn't necessarily pose a problem. Here's the data sheet for the film: http://www.fujifilm.com/products/professional_films/pdf/velvia_50_datasheet.pdf and you can use the eyeball exposure guide there to give you some confidence in the metering outcome, but I suspect you're over-worried when you don't need to be. :)

Comment: From what I understand, the DxOMark ISO ratings are based on the numeric values in the raw files, but have almost nothing to do with the JPEG produced after processing the raw. I'd expect the camera to meter for ISO 50, not ISO 73.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a dedicated light meter or even a phone application that does just that? It would be quite a bit less complicated then switching back and forth between the 5D and EOS300.

Exposure is exposure, you might have to account for a slight difference due to your film type, but other than that DSLR as compared to film photography is the same.

Comment: well for one because I have a DSLR but do not have an external meter, and I`ll want to bring the dslr
along anyway for live-view precision focus and composition and of course the ability to makes test shots
before I decide I wanna spend a film frame on a given scene.

As for phone-apps that do metering - while I have no experience using them I have several reasons
to believe they would be less than accurate or even consistent given limitations of most
smartphones cameras and software that is used to interact with them, is there a particular one that you
have used and found to be reliable ?

Comment: I use "Pocket Light Meter" by Nuwaste studios. It is an iOS app and it is free. I don't understand how focusing with your DSLR is going to help you take a shot with a different camera.

Comment: both are canon eos cameras, so the plan is to use the same lens which will be focused on the 5d mk2 and then removed and connected to the eos300, the error in focus should be limited to the minor differences between sensor/film alignment